# How do I make GIMP more colorful?

Tags: gimp

It seems almost everything in GIMP is colorless, even the tools on the top left corner:

[image: screenshot of icons]

Is it possible to make them colorful like in Windows or Mac?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Click on *Edit*, then *Preferences*.  Go down to *Interface* and set your **Theme** and your **Icon Theme**.  Enjoy!

[image]